# Passing value from app to component in a VueJS2 inline template component

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to get a simple value from app to an component which is an inline-template. I expected this to be easy, but cannot find anything in the docs to suggest where I'm going wrong.

Why cannot I see parentMessage in my component via a prop value?

```js
Vue.component('component1', {
  props: ['parentMessage'],
  data() {
    return {
     message: 'test',
     items: [
         {title: 'Milk', value: 5},
         {title: 'Bread', value: 3},
         {title: 'Sugar', value: 8}
     ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      // this.message = 'Updated Component 1'
    }
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
 data() {
  return {
   parentMessage: 'App Message'
  }
 }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <component1 inline-template>
      <div> 
        <h1 :message="parentMessage">{{ message }}</h1>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
          {{ item.title }}: {{ item.value }}
        </li>
      </div>
    </component1>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when using an `inline-template` you still need to pass the prop to the component via `:parent-message="parentMessage"` on the component tag.

Also, in the child component you are only binding `parentMessage` to the `message` attribute of an `h1` element. I'm not sure what you're expecting that to do, but it won't render the text to the page in any way.

Here's an example using your code, passing `parentMessage` from the parent to the child's prop and rendering the text in the `<h1>` element:

```js
Vue.component('component1', {
  props: ['parentMessage'],
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'test',
      items: [
        { title: 'Milk', value: 5 },
        { title: 'Bread', value: 3 },
        { title: 'Sugar', value: 8 }
      ]
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  data() {
    return { parentMessage: 'App Message' }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component1 inline-template :parent-message="parentMessage">
    <div> 
      <h1 v-if="parentMessage">{{ parentMessage }}</h1>
      <h1 v-else>{{ message }}</h1>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{ item.title }}: {{ item.value }}
      </li>
    </div>
  </component1>
</div>
```

---

From your comment, it seems like you're only trying to ever display a single message in the child component and want to be able to override a default value from the parent's scope.

To do that, make your `message` data property a prop with a default value of `'test'` (or whatever you eventually want the default to be). Then, you can pass a value for the `message` prop from the parent scope will overwrite the default value.

Here's an example for that too:

```js
Vue.component('component1', {
  props: {
    message: { 
      type: String,
      default: 'test',
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { title: 'Milk', value: 5 },
        { title: 'Bread', value: 3 },
        { title: 'Sugar', value: 8 }
      ]
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  data() {
    return { parentMessage: 'App Message' }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component1 inline-template :message="parentMessage">
    <div> 
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{ item.title }}: {{ item.value }}
      </li>
    </div>
  </component1>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought that :message="parentMessage" would set the message prop of the component or override it

Comment: That would be true if your `prop` name was `message` (it's not, it's `parentMessage`) and if you put it on the `<component1>` tag (you haven't, you've put it on an `<h1>` tag).

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, the fact that the component can't "see" the parent message unless it's passed in. Also your second example is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Appreciated buddy.